# Jquery parse values from json array and return coma separated

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

How can I extract values from json array:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Blue"}, {"id":2,"name":"Green"}, {"id":3,"name":"Red"}]
```

and return id's only in following format:

```
['1','2','3','4','5']
```

Comment: [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,you can use map() function on arrays

```js
var x = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Blue"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Green"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Red"
}];
var result = x.map(function(v) {
  return v.id + ''
})
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>')
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution partialy works, but I need to return id's as string wrapped with single quotes, as in my original post.

Comment: updated the snippet..check it